# What method is commonly used in industral manipulators

Tags: torque

Position control versus  torque control. What method is commonly used in industral manipulators

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Pari, but I'm afraid that questions like this really aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works. Also, the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) has good advice on how to write a good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, most pick and place robots use a version of position control, which they augment with feedforward dynamic models for improved speed and reduced errors.   Those robots which maintain contact with the environment (such as grinding, deburring, cutting, etc) usually implement a hybrid force/position control.